# Laravel Livewire : Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$name

Tags: php, laravel

As I mentioned before I have a problem in laravel livewire exactly in guards

I created a new guard and works fine in laravel but the problem in livewire

```
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
```

This my guard and everything works fine like `attemps` function and `logout`
But when I try to get the name of admin like

```
Auth::guard('admin')->name
```

this problem appears

```
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\work\livewire-admin-frontend-bootstrap\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$name` property is `protected`, meaning it cannot be accessed in all places. Please review the documentation for property visibility:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

If you need to access this `$name` property, you can use the `getName()` `getter`:

```php
Auth::guard('admin')->getName();
```

Here is the documentation for the `SessionGuard` class:

https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_getName